# Linux: Why does the FIFO scheduler not work as expected on the 1 core CPU machine?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am learning about Linux scheduler. Firstly, I want to test the FIFO scheduler. Here is the code I use to test:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Setting SCHED_FIFO and priority to %d\n",atoi(argv[1]));
  struct sched_param param;
  param.sched_priority = atoi(argv[1]);
  sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
  int n = 0;
  while(1) {
    n++;
    if (!(n % 10000000)) {
      printf("%s FIFO Prio %d running (n=%d)\n",argv[2], atoi(argv[1]),n);
    }
  }
}
```

I run this program with the priority 1 on 2 terminals: `./main 1`. Because my CPU has only 1 core, I expect only the first terminal can run because of the FIFO attribute. However, in the real-test situation: both terminal can run the code.

Here is my CPU information when I run the command `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6140 CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             2294.608
BogoMIPS:            4589.21
Virtualization:      VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            4096K
```

Please explain for me why.

Comment: Are you sure the FIFO scheduling policy is selected? You are not checking the return value of `sched_setscheduler(2)`. Also, are you running the program as root? It is a privileged syscall when the requested priority is higher than the value shown by `ulimit -r` (typically 0) and requires `CAP_SYS_NICE` or root privileges.

Comment: @HristoIliev wow. It is correct. I should run as root. Might I ask 2 questions: Why the program does not throw error? And how does it run when it is not root.

Comment: And I am happy if you post the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error since the syscall returns `-1` and you are expected to check the value of `errno`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check the return value of system calls and the corresponding value of `errno` when that return value is negative. In your case, you are likely not running the program with the right privileges. `sched_setscheduler(2)` requires `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability or running as root when you request scheduling policy `SCHED_FIFO` with priority higher than the soft limit of `RLIMIT_RTPRIO`, obtainable and settable using `ulimit -r`. The typical value of this resource limit is 0, which forbids unprivileged processes from requesting the FIFO scheduling policy.

See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) for a lot more details and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) for the possible error values.

Comment: thanks so much. Just a little more, when I print errno, the value is 1. When I check on the man page, 1 means "EPERM-Operation not permitted". Basically it is just another proof for your point.

Comment: As an aside, you can use the strerror function to convert an errno number to a string.